# Русские буквы отображаються знаком ( ??????????? ) MS SQL C#

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Sanix
{
    public partial class DriversLoad : Form
    {
        public DriversLoad()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void b_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string lastname = textBox1.Text;
            string name = textBox2.Text;
            string surname = textBox3.Text;
            string phone = textBox4.Text;
            string nambercar = textBox5.Text;
            string license = textBox6.Text;
            string pass = textBox7.Text;


            DB dB = new DB();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [Drivers] WHERE [lastname] = @ln AND [name] = @n AND [surname] = @sn", dB.getConnection());
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@ln", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastname;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@n", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = name;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@sn", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = surname;


            adapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
            adapter.Fill(dt);

            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ошибка, водитель уже существует!");
            }
            else
            {

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand($"INSERT INTO [Drivers](lastname, name, surname, phone, numbercar, license, pass) VALUES (@lastname, @name, @surname, @phone, @numbercar, @license, @pass)", dB.getConnection());

                cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = lastname;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", textBox4.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@numbercar", textBox5.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@license", textBox6.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", textBox7.Text);

                dB.openConnection();

                MessageBox.Show(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());

                dB.closeConnection();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Используйте для поля таблицы тип NVARCHAR вместо VARCHAR